# How to read line with space through redirection operator?

Tags: c

I am using command like `./a < input.txt > output.txt` to execute code

First, I tried to copy `input.txt` to `output.txt`, but I encounter some problem. Following is what I already tried.

1.copy all input content, but `scanf` will stop when it encounter space(and then do next iterate), even in same line

```
char buffer[1024]
while(scanf("%s",buffer)==1){
      printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
```

so expected answer is

```
hi abc
```

but what I get in `1` is

```
hi
abc
```

2.I tried modify `scanf` format, it only stop when encounter change line

```
scanf("%[^\n]",buffer)
```

but it will just only output one line, miss rest of text.

Are there any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: `it will just only output one line, miss rest of text.` - because you need to read the newline character too

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in reading and writing a full line at a time, use `fgets` instead:

```
char buffer[1024]
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) {
      fputs(buffer, stdout);
}
```

Comment: NOTE: `fgets()` will store the newline character into the buffer, so you may want to remove that. Removing can be done, for example, by `char* lf; if ((lf = strchr(buffer, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';`

Comment: MikeCAT, yes you are right. So I replace `puts` with `printf`

Comment: @MikeCAT OP seems to want to copy the whole file.  If that's the case, there's no need to strip anything out.  `fgets` will read the full line including the newline and `puts` will write exactly what was read.

Comment: @dbush No, `puts` will add a newline character. Maybe you want to use `fputs`, that don't add a newline character.

Comment: @MikeCAT Ah, I missed that.  Fixed.